# How to get status between two dates in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a query like this to get status without adding fields.

```sql
SELECT * ,
      IF(DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d"), CURDATE())<=0,"End","Running") status 
FROM agreements
```

the query is running but I want to add status if the end date is less than 3 days then the status will show "will be ended"

so there will be 3 statuses in the query, END, RUNNING, Will be END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CASE ..WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statements; also your `STR_TO_DATE(end, '%Y-%m-%d')` usage is unnecessary because [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function considers date part only for the calculation:

```sql
SELECT * ,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(end_date, CURDATE()) <= 0 THEN 'End' 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(end_date, CURDATE()) < 3 THEN 'Will Be End' 
            ELSE 'Running'
       END status
FROM agreements
```